# Why does my HP EliteBook 8440p doesn't turn on with 2 new DDR3 4gb RAMs?

Tags: windows, laptop, memory, motherboard, ddr

My HP EliteBook 8440p had 2 DDR3 RAM of 2GB each, so 4 GB total.

This is my DxDiag info:

[image: DxDiag info]

The specs of these 2 RAM are:

[image: RAM specification]

I wanted to change them to 2 4gb RAMs (so 8GB, the max supported ram for this laptop).

I bought 2 RAM, they are exactly the same, they have these specs:
DDR3, 4GB, 1600MHz (PC3-12800), CAS Latency 11, Voltage 1.35V.

But when I plug them and turn on the laptop it stays in a gray screen.

I can open the Bios and it even shows that now I have 8GB of RAM, but after that it doesn't start windows.

I tried plugging only one 4gb ram, tried plugging one 2gb and one 4gb, still doesn't run.
I plugged the 2 2GB RAMs again and it turns on like normally.

To be honest I bought the RAMs blindly, but as far as I know the speed doesn't matter, if the RAM is 1600MHz but my laptop supports max 1333MHz it should just use 1333MHz then.

Also all 1.35V RAMS are backwards compatible, so they should work with 1.5v even if my laptop doesn't support 1.35V?(Which I have no idea if it does) Isn't it?

And the latency shouldn't be a problem either, right?

The 2 new RAMs work because I tried it in another laptop and they work fine.

So I have no idea why my laptop stays in that gray screen, anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Your CPU [i5 M520](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/ru/ru/ark/products/47341/intel-core-i5520m-processor-3m-cache-2-40-ghz.html) does not support 4GB memory slots.
You can use up to 8GB of DDR3 800/1066 MHz RAM if your motherboard has 4 RAM slots.

Comment: According to cmd it has a max capacity of 8Gb and each slot runs at 1333MHz:    
C:\WINDOWS\system32>wmic memphysical get MaxCapacity, MemoryDevices.
MaxCapacity: 8388608.  MemoryDevices: 2.
      


C:\WINDOWS\system32>wmic memorychip get devicelocator, speed
Top-Slot 1(top):    1333.
Top-Slot 2(under): 1333.

Comment: Yes, QM57 supports DDR speed 1333Mhz only if you installs i7-720QM or higher with it, nor i5-520M

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

I had the Exact same issue with my HP 250 G5 Notebook after installing a second 4GB ram stick it worked and the next day it stopped so I sat all day testing both slots and both chips both were working fine in each slot individually but together my laptop wouldn't turn on so after a whole day of thinking and testing I decided to clean the ram slots and ram sticks with methylated spirits and then used a heat gun above the area of my ram memory controller (area where ram slots are located) but I took out the battery and power as well as the small battery on the motherboard first before doing any of this to avoid a shortage, never use a heat gun too close or for too long on a single are only use it for a few seconds at a time going in a clockwise or circular motion. After that I waited about 5 min out everything back together and both ram chips worked together simultaneously. Never had any problems again. Hope this helps.

Try cleaning the slots and sticks first without the heatgun process, you can use a hair dryer to dry the board if needed.